# Opening MacVim from Applescript

Tags: applescript, macvim

I am trying to create a simple Applescript that is activated each time I click a button on the Finder toolbar. This script opens MacVim with the working directory set to the directory that the Finder is at. This is as close as I have got ...

```
on run
    tell application "Finder" to get folder of the front window as string
    set workingDir to POSIX path of result
    do shell script "cd \"" & workingDir & "\"; /usr/local/bin/mvim"
end run
```

This works great (mvim automatically sets the working directory of MacVim to the cwd). However for some reason this only works once. It beach balls for a short while and nothing happens If I click the button again. I would have expected to get another blank MacVim window - just as I had typed mvim again in the terminal.

How do I ge the script to do this?

Comment: Just a quick clarification. If you would like to just open a directory from to Finder to MacVim you can right click on the folder and click on New MacVim buffer here. It is just two clicks away.

Comment: Ah that is worth knowing. This works for folders under the current folder, but for the current folder itself, it is not obvious which links/references that this will work for (it does work on the breadcrumb trail at the bottom, but not for a shortcut I placed in the panel to the left for example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next calls beachball because the first one is not finished.

To be able to background an applescript process, it must have no dangling output so, change your `do shell script`line to:

```
do shell script "cd \"" & workingDir & "\"; /usr/local/bin/mvim > /dev/null 2>&1"
```

it should do the trick.

Comment: It does work but I'm not sure why. As far as I know this redirects SDTERR and STDIN to the bitbucket, but the `mvim` script does not generate any output anyway. I also tried backgrounding the process with `&` at the end but that didn't work - why is that?

Comment: AFAIK even if mvim already backgrounds itself and does not generate any output, the fact it grabs 2 file descriptors is enough for Applescript not to be able to _guess_ that it will **never** produce any output. You thus need to explicitly release the file descriptors...

Answer (score 4):

This opens the selected files/folders in MacVim.
<strike>Works only when a single item is selected in Finder.</strike> Works with multiple items selected in Finder.

I used 'open -a' to overcome the mvim script limitation to open multiple files in tabs, as explained [here](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-do-I-open-a-file-from-the-Terminal-into-MacVim-s-current-window-td1220082.html)

```
on run
    tell application "Finder" to set selectedFiles to selection
    if selectedFiles is {} then return    
    set filePathPosix to ""
    repeat with filePath in selectedFiles
        set filePathPosix to filePathPosix & "'" & POSIX path of (filePath as alias) & "' "
    end repeat
    do shell script "open -a MacVim " & filePathPosix & " > /dev/null 2>&1"
end run
```

Comment: I have improved the answer, now it can open multiple files together.